# Android: Google Play Store fake refund

Tags: android, google-play

My app published on the Play Store had 4 refunds but in the Google Play Developer Console I see that in the "installation active/total" section my app has 71/71. It looks like people who asked for refund have now the app installed in their devices. Is it possible?

Comment: "`How to Ask` Is your question about programming?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is possible if the app was installed, and then the user lost an internet connection so the device doesn't know its been refunded and hasn't uninstalled it yet.

It is also possible that the statistics have not been updated to reflect uninstalls yet (once every 24 hours)

It is also possible that the 4 uninstalls did take place, but other users have it installed on more than one device (a single Google account may install a purchased app on unlimited devices, and they will all show up as individual installs)

Comment: Thanks, I think these are more likely the third option. Is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: @TheModularMind No, you have no control over that.